# How to manually link libraries in g++ on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu

Im trying to manually link external library with c++ on ubuntu. Since this is my first c++ project I'm missing some basics.
This is my code (this tries to connect to spread):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sp.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int status;
    status = SP_connect("4803@localhost", "test1", 0, 0, 0, 0);
    cout << "done\n";
    return 0;
}
```

If I just try to run it with

```
user@computer:~/thesis$ g++ -o example1 test.cpp
/tmp/cczPLZQ0.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `SP_connect'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As far as I understand I need to link a library, I tried to do it with -l

```
kristjan@kupo:~/thesis$ g++ -o example1 test.cpp -llibspread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibspread
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also tried this (I'm shooting in the dark here):

```
user@computer:~/thesis$ g++ -o example1 test.cpp $(pkg-config -cflags /usr/local/lib/libspread) $(pkg-config --libs /usr/local/lib/libspread)

-cflags: unknown option
Package /usr/local/lib/libspread was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `/usr/local/lib/libspread.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package '/usr/local/lib/libspread' found
/tmp/ccU8GTC2.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `SP_connect'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `-lspread` would be the right option if the .so file is in a standard location.

Comment: You should skip the lib in the -llibspread just use -lspread

Answer (score 2):

As @Mat said you should use `-lspread` and omit the `lib` prefix.